# Is there ng-bootstrap/BS5 beta documentation?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am working on an experimental branch of my project with Bootstrap 5, making changes to my HTML and CSS as needed.

Some of my UI is plain Bootstrap and some is ng-bootstrap.  I can update the BS stuff with the code snippets from their new docs.

But the ng-bootstrap output looks just like the pre-updated Bootstrap. Will there be updated code for 12.x?  Is there any beta documentation, or do I just need to leave the styling broken until there is?

For example, here's how my toggle buttons looked in both BS and ng-bootstrap versions with Bootstrap 5 installed:

[image: bs5 before]

and after I updated the bootstrap 5 HTML:

[image]

but the NG one is still broken.  If this will be fixed with new ng-bootstrap snippets, I will need to wait.  I am just checking.

Comment: they're not random. those were expressions not to be taken literally; for example it wasn't really broken it just appeared so. I didn't want to come off that I felt something was broken and needed to be fixed.

Comment: They _are_ broken if they don't appear as desired.